# ngx-editor link redirects to url combined with angular project url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, ngx-editor

so I am using ngx-editor with angular 6 to have Rich Text support. I want to add links in the paragraph and on link click, open url in new tab.

On html page, I am dynamically rendering data as:

```
<div [innerHTML]="Description"></div>
```

where Description is typescript string var.

My problem is, when I click on the link rendered from above html code, it opens url as:

http://localhost:4200/www.google.com

where I added `www.google.com` as link from ngx-editor window.

I want it to redirect to `www.google.com`.

So I want solution to remove project URL from link URL and open only link URL dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ngx-editor is discontinued. Check our fork: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iget/editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add http:// or https:// when creating your link.